# Scala Convert a Map[String, List[String]] to a Map[String, String]

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, collections

Would someone be able to help me convert Map[String, List[String]] to a Map[String, String] in scala?

Here is the Map[String, List[String]] as follows:

```
val pets: Map[String, List[String]] = Map(
    "home" -> List("cat", "dog", "fish"),
    "farm" -> List("cow", "horse"), 
    "wild" -> List("tiger", "elephant")
)
```

That needs to be converted to Map[String, String] as follows:

```
val pets2: Map[String, String] = Map(
    "home" -> "cat",
    "home" -> "dog",
    "home" -> "fish",
    "farm" -> "cow",
    "farm" -> "horse",
    "wild" -> "tiger",
    "wild" -> "elephant"
)
```

Comment: What you are asking is impossible. Maps can't have repeated keys.

Comment: But it does have a MultiMap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned before each key in a `Map` is unique.

That said, what you **can** do is convert the map to a sequence of tuples:

```
pets.toSeq.flatMap { case (key, list) => list.map(key -> _) }
```

will give you:

```
ArrayBuffer(
  (home,cat), 
  (home,dog), 
  (home,fish), 
  (farm,cow), 
  (farm,horse), 
  (wild,tiger), 
  (wild,elephant)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maps cannot have repeated keys.